# How do i search for a specific username by id

Tags: query

i am trying to find out how to search the cms database for a specific users username based on their user id and not based on logged in.

Any documentation links or advice would be great, have tried using various ways but ultimately i think query is the way but i am unsure of how to find a specific users username.

i have tried this but i need to do this using the ee() classes in some way as i cannoe seem to define a php variable with the following :

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT screen_name FROM exp_members WHERE member_id = '1' "}
        {screen_name}
{/exp:query}
```

please advise and many thanks!

Comment: Can you expand your question as it's not clear what you're asking, queries are the right approach dependent on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you want to do this with a php approach over using the exp:query because of some php variable you want to use with it?
If so, check out the [Database Class Docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html) over in the EE documentation.

Since we know that only one member will have an id of one, we can use a simple query like so:

```
$results = ee()->db->order_by('member_id')
 ->limit(1)
 ->get('exp_members');
 ->where(array('exp_members.memberr_id'=> '1'));

$first_member = $results->row('screen_name');
```